# Android TextureView / Drawing / Painting Performance

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, drawing, textureview

I am attempting to make a drawing/painting app using `TextureView` on Android. I want to support a drawing surface of up to 4096x4096 pixels, which seems reasonable for my minimum target device (which I use for testing) which is a Google Nexus 7 2013 which has a nice quad core CPU and 2GB memory.

One of my requirements is that my view must be inside of a view that allows it to be zoomed in and out and panned, which is all custom code I have written (think UIScrollView from iOS).

I've tried using a regular View (not `TextureView`) with OnDraw and performance was absolutely horrible - less than 1 frame a second. This happened even if I called `Invalidate(rect)` with only the rect that changed. I tried turning off hardware acceleration for the view, but nothing rendered, I assume because 4096x4096 is too big for software.

I then tried using `TextureView` and performance is a little better - about 5-10 frames per second (still terrible but better). The user draws into a bitmap, which is then later drawn into the texture using a background thread. I'm using Xamarin but hopefully the code makes sense to Java people.

```
private void RunUpdateThread()
{
    try
    {
        TimeSpan sleep = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0f / 60.0f);
        while (true)
        {
            lock (dirtyRect)
            {
                if (dirtyRect.Width() > 0 && dirtyRect.Height() > 0)
                {
                    Canvas c = LockCanvas(dirtyRect);
                    if (c != null)
                    {
                        c.DrawBitmap(bitmap, dirtyRect, dirtyRect, bufferPaint);
                        dirtyRect.Set(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        UnlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(sleep);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

If I change lockCanvas to pass null instead of a rect, performance is great at 60 fps, but the contents of the `TextureView` flicker and get corrupted, which is disappointing. I would have thought it would simply be using an OpenGL frame buffer / render texture underneath or at least have an option to preserve contents.

Are there any other options short of doing everything in raw OpenGL in Android for high performance drawing and painting on a surface that is preserved in between draw calls?

Comment: 4096x4096 is pretty huge. I'm not surprised you're having performance issues. Do you absolutely need an image that big? You might check out the graphics architecture: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html.

Comment: @DavidM Yes that is a requirement. I've built a similar app on iOS using core graphics, UIScrollView and on iPad Air, performance is just fine at 4096x4096. The 2013 Nexus 7 should perform better than iPad Air or at least comparable I would think.

Comment: @DavidM What really gets me is that performance is great if I pass null to the lockCanvas call, but then the texture contents seem to get corrupted... it is very odd that lockCanvas(rect) would be slower than a lockCanvas(null)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*UPDATE* I ditched TextureView and now use an OpenGL view where I call glTexSubImage2D to update changed pieces of a render texture.

*OLD ANSWER*
I ended up tiling TextureView in a 4x4 grid. Depending on the dirty rect each frame, I refresh the appropriate TextureView views. Any view that is not updated that frame I call Invalidate on.

Some devices, such as the Moto G phone have an issue where the double buffering is corrupted for one frame. You can fix that by calling lockCanvas twice when the parent view has it's onLayout called.

```
private void InvalidateRect(int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
    dirtyRect.Set(l, t, r, b);

    foreach (DrawSubView v in drawViews)
    {
        if (Rect.Intersects(dirtyRect, v.Clip))
        {
            v.RedrawAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            v.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    Invalidate();
}

protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ChildCount; i++)
    {
        View v = GetChildAt(i);
        v.Layout(v.Left, v.Top, v.Right, v.Bottom);
        DrawSubView sv = v as DrawSubView;
        if (sv != null)
        {
            sv.RedrawAsync();

            // why are we re-drawing you ask? because of double buffering bugs in Android :)
            PostDelayed(() => sv.RedrawAsync(), 50);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31124496/ had a similar problem, and was also able to resolve it by calling invalidate. I've filed http://b.android.com/178525 .

Comment: @fadden Looks like it, that's great! I ended up layering software views in my grid as they performed better than both TextureView and hardware layers.

Answer (score 22):

First off, if you want to understand what's going on under the hood, you need to read the [Android Graphics Architecture document](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html).  It's long, but if you sincerely want to understand the "why", it's the place to start.

**About TextureView**

TextureView works like this: it has a Surface, which is a queue of buffers with a producer-consumer relationship.  If you're using software (Canvas) rendering, you lock the Surface, which gives you a buffer; you draw on it; then you unlock the Surface, which sends the buffer to the consumer.  The consumer in this case is in the same process, and is called SurfaceTexture or (internally, more aptly) GLConsumer.  It converts the buffer into an OpenGL ES texture, which is then rendered to the View.

If you turn off hardware acceleration, GLES is disabled, and TextureView cannot do anything.  This is why you got nothing when you turned hardware acceleration off.  [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) is very specific: "TextureView can only be used in a hardware accelerated window. When rendered in software, TextureView will draw nothing."

If you specify a dirty rect, the software renderer will memcpy the previous contents into the frame *after* rendering is complete.  I don't believe it sets a clip rect, so if you call drawColor(), you will fill the entire screen, and then have those pixels overwritten.  If you aren't currently setting a clip rect, you may see some performance benefit from doing so.  (I didn't check the code though.)

The dirty rect is an in-out parameter.  You pass the rect you want in when you call `lockCanvas()`, and the system is allowed to modify it before the call returns.  (In practice, the only reason it would do this would be if there were no previous frame or the Surface were resized, in which case it would expand it to cover the entire screen.  I think this would have been better handled with a more direct "I reject your rect" signal.)  You're required to update every pixel inside the rect you get back.  You are *not* allowed to alter the rect, which you appear to be trying to do in your sample -- whatever is in the dirty rect after `lockCanvas()` succeeds is what you're required to draw on.

I suspect the dirty rect mis-handling is the source of your flickering.  Sadly, this is an easy mistake to make, as the behavior of the `lockCanvas()` `dirtyRect` arg is only documented in [the Surface class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html#lockCanvas(android.graphics.Rect)) itself.

**Surfaces and buffering**

All Surfaces are double- or triple-buffered.  There is no way around this -- you cannot read and write simultaneously and not get tearing.  If you want a single buffer that you can modify and push when desired, that buffer will need to be locked, copied, and unlocked, which creates stalls in the composition pipeline.  For best throughput and latency, flipping buffers is better.

If you want the lock-copy-unlock behavior, you can write that yourself (or find a library that does it), and it will be as efficient as it would be if the system did it for you (assuming you're good with blit loops).  Draw to an off-screen Canvas and blit the bitmap, or to a OpenGL ES FBO and blit the buffer.  You can find an example of the latter in Grafika's "[record GL app](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/RecordFBOActivity.java#953)" Activity, which has a mode that renders once off-screen, and then blits twice (once for display, once for recording video).

**More speed and such**

There are two basic ways to draw pixels on Android: with Canvas, or with OpenGL.  Canvas rendering to a Surface or Bitmap is always done in software, while OpenGL rendering is done with the GPU.  The only exception is that, when rendering to a [custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html), you can opt to use hardware acceleration, but this does not apply when rendering to the Surface of a SurfaceView or TextureView.

A drawing or painting app can either remember the drawing commands, or just throw pixels at a buffer and use that as its memory.  The former allows for deeper "undo", the latter is much simpler, and has increasingly better performance as the amount of stuff to render grows.  It sounds like you want to do the latter, so blitting from off-screen makes sense.

Most mobile devices have a hardware limitation of 4096x4096 or smaller for GLES textures, so you won't be able to use a single texture for anything larger.  You can query the size limit value (GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE), but you may be better off with an internal buffer that is as large as you want, and just render the portion that fits on screen.  I don't know what the Skia (Canvas) limitation is offhand, but I believe you can create much larger Bitmaps.

Depending on your needs, a SurfaceView may be preferable to a TextureView, as it avoids the intermediate GLES texture step.  Anything you draw on the Surface goes directly to the system compositor (SurfaceFlinger).  The down side to this approach is that, because the Surface's consumer is not in-process, there is no opportunity for the View system to handle the output, so the Surface is an independent layer.  (For a drawing program this could be beneficial -- the image being drawn is on one layer, your UI is on a separate layer on top.)

FWIW, I haven't looked at the code, but Dan Sandler's [Markers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dsandler.apps.markers&hl=en) app might be worth a peek (source code [here](https://github.com/dsandler/markers)).

**Update:** the corruption was [identified as a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178525) and [fixed in 'L'](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/70735bd).

Comment: I was using a standard View with ondraw when I turned off hardware acceleration. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Thanks for your well thought out response. I've experimented with tiling TextureView views, but I am getting some weird rendering artifacts when I lock and post the canvas of multiple texture views in quick succession. Any ideas why that might be? Does TextureView only support one instance?

Comment: SurfaceView is not a good option because I am embedding the draw view inside my own custom ViewGroup that acts as a UIScrollView for zooming and panning.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're seeing bad behavior while using multiple TextureViews. There's no inherent limitation. Grafika's "double decode" activity plays video to a pair of them with no weird effects. In my experience this sort of issue is usually caused by missing synchronization on multi-threaded rendering code, but if you're single-threaded then that's not an issue.

Comment: I've tried doing everything on the UI thread and multi-threading, both show the same strange glitch.

Comment: Whatever approach you adopt needs to avoid copying 64MB of data every frame in software. That means not passing a dirty rect to `lockCanvas()`, and not drawing the entire bitmap into a TextureView every frame. The best you can do is to render onto a GLES FBO that is blitted by the GPU, as that avoids the slow path altogether. For Canvas rendering you have to choose between copying 64MB into a huge TextureView (slow drawing, fast scrolling) or just blitting the visible portion each frame into a small one (fast drawing, slow scrolling). You could adopt a hybrid approach that switches on the fly.

Comment: One other thing: I have zero experience with Xamarin, so I don't know what effects it could be having on the performance or correctness.

Comment: Is there a fast way to render a Bitmap onto a GLES FBO? Would I have to convert it to a texture or is there a faster way?

Comment: I don't think it's Xamarin because the problem only happens on my Moto G running Kitkat. My Nexus 7 running Lollipop does not exhibit the problem.

Comment: I found the problem. Apparently, if you are updating ANY TextureView views, you must update ALL TextureView views for the current run loop cycle. This can be done via lockCanvas which is slower, or via Invalidate which simply re-presents what was last showing, but avoids the corruption issue.

Comment: Awesome! I can draw at 60 FPS on my crappy MotoG with a 4096x4096 image :)

Comment: I also had to add a second lock canvas to force a re-draw and buffer flip in onlayout, but now I'm not getting any corruption at all.

Comment: If you've got a solution that addresses all your problems, it would be very helpful if you could write up the details in an answer (perhaps replacing the one you already provided). The TextureView issue sounds like something the Android framework team should look into. The "dual decode" player in Grafika plays two movies side-by-side into two TextureViews at different (sub-60fps) frame rates, with no corruption, so something odd is going on. At any rate, I'm glad you've got it working.