# Multiple TextureViews duplication content

Tags: android, android-canvas, textureview

I use custom TextureView to draw animation. Drawing runs in separate thread - here is drawing code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(currentFrameRate);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null)
                canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            drawItems(canvas);
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null)
                unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

I use two of these controls in LinearLayout - one below other. But sometimes on some devices one control begin duplicate another if no animation in it at this moment.

Thanks for advance.

UPD: Maybe it helps - both of my views placed over SurfaceView.

Comment: What version of Android? I'd like to rule out https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178525

Comment: Android version 4.4.4

Comment: The bug wasn't fixed until 5.x, so that could be an issue. The bug report, and the stackoverflow questions linked from it, have some workarounds that might be worth trying.

Comment: Eventually this helps me http://stackoverflow.com/a/33052904/2165327